# Is it bad programming practice to have a function that prints statement?

Tags: c++, function, oop, printing

I'd like to know if it is poor programming practice to have a class that has a function that only prints output to the screen?

***Simple example for understanding purposes:***
Student class has the usual set and get methods but it also has a function called `void PrintStudentDetails();`

Should it be done in the main as such:

```cpp
cout << "Name: " << student.GetName() << endl;

cout << "Age: " << student.GetAge() << endl;

cout << "Gender: " << student.GetGender() << endl;
```

Or as an object calling the print function in the main as such:

```cpp
student.PrintStudentDetails();
```

Please advise me on the proper coding practices.

Comment: For cases like this, you may wish to look into [overloading the I/O operators](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/).

Comment: If your program is small, that's fine. Something more modular would be to define an overloaded `operator >>` for the class, or to have a function that takes an `ostream&` as in input parameter. Then if you want to change your output stream (use something other than cout) you can

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the advice. I am quite fond of the idea of operator overloading but I am unsure about how many different operator overloading functions a class can have. Do you happen to know if there are any limitations?

Comment: @JinYuChan There's not limitations that I'm aware of. Overloaded operators are just fancy-named functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Version

Overload the [insertion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion).

## TL;DR Version

While there is nothing harmful about a function that only writes to `cout`, it is much more useful, and no harder to write, a function that can write to any `ostream`.

```cpp
void Student::PrintStudentDetails(std::ostream & out) // pass in any out stream
{
    out << "Name: " << student.GetName() << '\n'
        << "Age: " << student.GetAge() << '\n'
        << "Gender: " << student.GetGender() << '\n';
}
```

Note: insertion operators can chain.

Side note: `std::endl` is a new line AND a stream flush, and that stream flush can be very expensive. Generally you only want to flush when you have to to push information immediately to a client or the stream's buffer is full. Prefer to use `'\n'` to `endl` in most other cases.

It is only marginally more difficult to write a `<<` overload that prints your class so you can `anystream << myClassInstance;`.

```cpp
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, // any outstream
                          const Student & student) // the object to print
{
    out << "Name: " << student.GetName() << '\n'
        << "Age: " << student.GetAge() << '\n'
        << "Gender: " << student.GetGender() << '\n';
    return out; // this is the magic that allows chaining
}
```

You can now

```cpp
cout << myStudent;
```

Note: the insertion operator is often implemented as a `friend` of the class in order to provide easy access to `private` variables.

For more wisdom on overloading operators read [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I would like to ask a question about operator overloading. How many instances of operator overloading can one do for a single class?

Comment: Limited only by the number of operators and sensible permutations of the parameters.

Comment: Assuming the declaration and implementation have already been done for the example below. Does that mean I can have multiple operators as such:

os << "Name: " << student.GetName() << endl

     << "Age: " << student.GetAge();


os2 << "Name: " << student.GetName() << endl

       << "Age: " << student.GetAge() << endl

       << "Gender: " << student.GetGender() << endl;

Comment: @JinYuChan Ahhhh! That's what you meant. Yes. You can effectively chain operators forever. Note: as of the C++17 Standard revision you can even have a computation being output depend on results from a previous computation in the same output. Before C++17 you cannot be assured that all of the operations will be sequenced in order if the compiler figured the program could be more efficient out of order.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the advice.